# Bus error using matplotlibcpp.h and plot() function (macOS)

Tags: c++, matplotlib, plot

I get zsh: bus error on the following piece of code:

```
#include <vector>
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"

int main() {
  std::vector<int> x{1,2,3,4}; // error persists when using doubles
  std::vector<int> y{1,2,3,4};

  matplotlibcpp::plot(x, y);
  matplotlibcpp::savefig("figure");

  return 0;
}
```

I am new to C++ and this is the first time I am trying to plot in C++. Any advice?

I am running macOS Big Sur (11.6) and VS Code. I compile in g++-11. Python (v3.9) was installed in Homebrew and I have recently updated most of the packages. The code works if I just output "Hello world" for example so the error is coming from the plot() or savefig()

Comment: Have you followed the matplotlibpp requirements and installed matplotlib via pip `pip3 install matplotlib` or `python3 -m pip install matplotlib`?

Comment: @273K yes, I used pip3 install matplotlib